# How to add fixed container 740px on bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, containers, fixed

This is CSS code

```
#container{
    width:740px;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:30px;
    margin:60px auto;
}
```

This code not work on bootstrap. How to add this fixed container on bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `container` is a class since you're using bootstrap.

It should have `.` instead of `#` selector

```
.container {
  width:740px;
  background-color:#fff;
  padding: 30px;
  margin:60px auto;
}
```